# What damage can 1500V cause to a circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ohms-law, electrically-conductive, circuit-theory

I'm working on a device that has a supply of 220 V. The output has an LED at the end of a fibre-optic cable coming from the device in question.
If, for some reason, a tremendous amount of voltage passes through the circuit inside, what could happen to the LED and the circuit inside the device?

I'm guessing a large amount of current will flow through in such a case, but is there any chance that the current will be limited while voltage shoots up?

Also, what are some methods I can implement to limit such a thing from happening?

Comment: All of it? How long is the duration? Products are required to withstand 2 kV lightning impulse for 8/20 us to be put on the market in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but this is a hopelessly vague question and with irrelevant details such as "a fibre-optic cable coming from the device in question". What has that got to do with lightning? You have given no details other than 220 V in and that it has an LED on the device. Fault and risk analysis is impossible.

Comment: Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Any questions?

As for trying to prevent the above from happening, how hard that is depends largely on the total energy available.  If it's something like a static discharge with small and finite energy, then a resistor and diodes might be enough.  If it's 1.5 kV capable of mA and sustained for seconds, then it will be much much harder to protect against and not interfere with the intended signal.  This gets complicated, and you may have to scale back the characteristics of the intended signal.  This is not worth getting into without more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

When you exceed the voltage limits of the device, any number of things can happen. Generally, the voltage will break down the dielectrics in one of the components and short out, burning the component due to high amounts of current flow.

Surge protectors are designed to protect against spikes in voltage. I'm sure other options are also available.